# How to remove \x00 ... \xff

Tags: string, python-3.x, decode

How to remove those "\x00...\xff" in a string ? there is a way to do that ?
example:

> `'\x00\x00\x00\xea\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\x11\x14\xb3\x00\x01\x01MYDATAISHEREEEEE\x00\x01'`

Comment: what are the exact characters to remove?

Comment: Define a regex for what you want to remove and then try string.replace

Comment: how to do it? please help me

Answer (score 1):

I would search the string for the pattern you're looking for, rather than replacing characters that don't match.
 In this case, I doubt you want the `ê` to show up, so you'll only want the characters `A-Z`:

```
import re

data = '\x00\x00\x00\xea\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x14'\
       '\xb3\x00\x01\x01MYDATAISHEREEEEE\x00\x01'

p = re.compile('[A-Z]+')
data = p.search(data).group()
print(data)
```